# Propel_Generator - include paths in the classmap-file incorrect

Tags: propel

i am using the propel runtime v1.5.4 and its related propel_generator in my zend_framework/php project since two years without any problems.

Yesterday i have updated the propel_generator via pear to v1.6.5 and the runtime library to v1.6.6. After the first build-proccess with the new generator i have a problem with the generated classmap-[project]-conf.php file:

Old Generator (v1.5.4)

```
...

      'AutocompleteQuery' => 'AutocompleteQuery.php',
      'AutocompleteTableMap' => 'map/AutocompleteTableMap.php',
      'BaseAclAssertion' => 'om/BaseAclAssertion.php'

...
```

New Generator (v1.6.5)

```
...

      'AutocompleteQuery' => 'AutocompleteQuery.php',
      'AutocompleteTableMap' => '/map/AutocompleteTableMap.php',
      'BaseAclAssertion' => '/om/BaseAclAssertion.php'

...
```

The new generator adds a leading slash before the 'map' and 'om' path. So the propel autoloader can not find the class-files.

Is there any config-option or a generator-template where i can change this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the `targetPackage` build property is empty in your configuration. By default, Propel uses the project name as target package, so that you always have a directory before your classes:

```
  // ...
  'AutocompleteQuery'    => 'project/AutocompleteQuery.php',
  'AutocompleteTableMap' => 'project/map/AutocompleteTableMap.php',
  'BaseAclAssertion'     => 'project/om/BaseAclAssertion.php'
```

I fixed Propel to remove this limitation, that way it will generate a valid package path. I'm talking about packages here because packages are used to determine where to write files.

Documentation to understand packages in Propel:
http://www.propelorm.org/cookbook/multi-component-data-model.html#understanding_packages

Fixed by commit:
https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/commit/b03569a802471b86e6e52287974de17f836c9baa